# List 'Documents' does not exist at site - Powershell query

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am running a PowerShell script to get a list of all documents in a document library, the URL is :

https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

This is the error message :
**Error Generating Version History Report! Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "List 'Documents' does not exist at site with URL 'https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC'."**

I have tried changing the $LibraryName to "Shared Documents" and "Shared%20Documents" without succcess.

````
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Set Parameters
$SiteURL="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/"
$LibraryName="Documents"

    #Upload Credentials 
    [SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $AdminPassword -AsPlainText -Force 
    $credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $AdminName, $(convertto-securestring $AdminPassword -asplaintext -force)
    $AdminSiteURL="https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com"

    #Connect to SharePoint Online Admin Center
    Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminSiteURL –Credential $credentials

    #Get All site collections
    $SiteCollections = Get-SPOSite -Limit All


Try {

     #Upload Credentials 
    [SecureString]$SecureUserPass = ConvertTo-SecureString $userPassword -AsPlainText -Force 
    $Credentials = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $userPassword -asplaintext -force)

    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

    int.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    #$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials_2

    #Get the web & Library
    $Web=$Ctx.Web
    $Ctx.Load($Web)
    $List = $Web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()



    ----------"code fails here" ----------
    ......}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could check the library name in library setting.
[image]

When I changed the library name, your problem was reproduced. When you keep the name in the code and the library name the same, the code is fine.

**My test result:**
[image]

Comment: I changed the document library name to **Document2** to test your theory, and got the same error:


Error Generating Version History Report! Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "List 'Documents2' does not exist at site with URL 'https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/NRG'."